# How can I prevent user from inserting characters in Text Box other than Only numbers can insert jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I implemented **iphone&android app in jQuery mobile.* i used **pure jQuery mobile**

To enter phone `number in a text box. I used TYPE=”TEL”' this is for numaric keypad.

```
<input type="tel" style=" width:81%;" id="contactNumber" value="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" />
```

**But user can enter text also the text box which is unnecessary thing.**

**`How can I prevent user from inserting characters other than numbers?`**

For mobile devices users it would be much more comfortable if the only input possibile is numeric, as they must press each button to get a number rather than a letter!

I tried adding `TYPE=”TEL”  TYPE=”mumber”` in the input field, but it does not work to prevent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactNumber').keyup(function() {
        var numbers = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(numbers.replace(/\D/, ''));
    });
});
```

This should replace any non-digit with an empty character *as they are put in, negating the need to search for more than one non-digit at a time.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactNumber').keyup(function() {
        var numbers = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(numbers.replace(/\D/, ''));
    });
});  After I wrote this I realized this is not updating the value.  Just rap numbers.replace() in a $(this).val() and that should be good.

Comment: I modified the answer.  I realized that originally this wasn't updating the value of #contactNumber.  Now, it is.  I haven't used JQuery mobile before, so I don't know if it responds to .keyup in the usual way.  You could throw this in as a quick test:  $('#contactNumber').keyup(function() {alert("works");});

Comment: Can you add a check for negative integers on this also. @Dale

Comment: I got it only + did that. 
$(this).val(numbers.replace(/\D+/, ''));

worked.

Answer (score 7):

None of the above worked for me but I found a solution that works perfectly for what I needed (to disallow special characters in an input field). Prevents and alerts user.

```
    <script>
     $("#userlogin").keypress(function(e) {
      if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]/)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Special characters are not allowed. Use 'A-Z', 'a-z' and '0-9'.");
       }
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seen this answered before.  Check out  http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

And you can simply change your class id and have this code on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you could write your own function and call it onkeyup event

See: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html

Another option is using step attribute:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.step.float

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" >
```

Answer (score 1):

type="tel"  is HTML 5, and not jqueryMobile.
the later devices whose browsers support HTML 5 input types render these boxes fine. But for older versions, the additional scripts need to be there. The scrips are already posted in above answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contactNumber').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        event = event || window.event; canAdd = new Boolean(false);
        canAdd = ((event.charCode > 47) && (event.charCode < 58) || (event.charCode == 32) || (event.charCode == 40) || (event.charCode == 41) || (event.charCode == 43) || (event.charCode == 45) || (event.charCode == 124));
        if (!canAdd && event.charCode)
            return false;
    });
```

But better to use HTML5 tel attrubute

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** :

```
 input type="tel" (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)"
```

**Script** :

```
isNumberKey(evt: any) { < br >
        // to accept only numbers in contact field<br>
        if ( < br >
            (evt.key >= '0' && evt.key <= '9') || < br >
            evt.key == "Backspace" || < br >
            evt.key == "Delete" || < br >
            evt.key == "ArrowLeft" || < br >
            evt.key == "ArrowRight" < br >
        ) { < br > //"Backspace" etc for 'firefox' browser<br>
                return true; < br >
        } < br >
        return false; < br >
}
```